# Strange exposure of a PostGIS layer in QGIS after importing OSM data into a database

Tags: qgis, postgis, srid, osm2pgsql

I've imported a osm layer into my postgres/postgis database.

```
osm2pqsql -E 3857 -c -S /usr/share/osm2pgsql/default.style -H localhost -W -d landslide -U postgres oberpfalz-latest.osm.bz2
```

During the import there were several warnings like this:

```
Processing: Node(3261k 69.4k/s) Way(399k 7.27k/s) Relation(80 26.67/s) Standard exception processing way_id 33907: TopologyException: side location conflict at 1396469.99 6361915.7599999998
```

Accept of this, I think the import runs without any problems.

After that I added planet_osm_roads to my qgis-project (EPSG:3857).

The result is shown in the picture below. I tried to change the SRIDs, but no change.

[image]

Any ideas what this strange exposure comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few possible reasons:

- Your version of osm2pgsql is not ready for 64-bit-long node numbers. Try the latest version
- Updating of the planet at Geofabrik failed before cutting into pieces. The OSM Inspector has such lines too at the moment. There is not much to do but complaining at Geofabrik.
- You get that kind of error if boundary polygons are missing some elements. The cutting polygons of Geofabrik are sometimes a bit too close.

Comment: When I add the planet_osm_point layer everything is correct. At first I will update my osm2pgsql version.

Comment: Points can not have missing elements, so you won't see the mistake.

Comment: The answer is updating osm2pgsql. Thanks a lot!